# How to find max and min values based on the median and 95%CI from a summary table?

Tags: ggplot2, max, min

I'm trying to plot a boxplot of median survival times and their 95%CI, since my KM curve is too busy. `geom_boxplot()` requires a min and max values. How to calculate these off the median and CI?

Side question: Any better plot for such task?
P.S. In my code I made up some values to get the whiskers of the plot

```
df=data.frame(var=c("Z+", "Z-","M-/Z-", "M-/Z+", "M+/Z-", "M+/Z+"),
              m=c(4.2, 5.7, 3.8, 5.1, 4.9, 6.6),
              ci_l=c(4, 5.5, 3.6, 4.9, 4.6, 6),
              ci_u=c(4.3, 6, 4, 5.5, 5.5, 7.5))

df%>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = m, x=var,m)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(
    lower = ci_l, 
    upper = ci_u, 
    middle = m, 
    ymin = m - ci_u/m, 
    ymax = m + ci_u/m),
    stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Boxplots are not parameterised by 95% CI's, so plotting these values as a boxplots may cause confusion in your audience. I'd simply go with `geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = ci_l, ymax = ci_u))` if you don't have access to the original data.